# How to randomly select an integer from a list in Java?

Tags: java, random, integer

Here is what I have so far:

```
private int [] delays = {1000, 1333, 3443, 1220, 3232};
```

I want to have a function where it will sleep for a moment before continuing:

```
sleep(random(delays))
```

I have found solutions for strings however when it comes to integers I dont really understand it.

I have imported the random. I got:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
int delayIndex = rand.nextInt(delays.length);
```

however it says: The method nextInt(int, int) in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Thanks for neg repping me.

I appreciate your help however the problem I am geting is still occuring:

The method nextInt(int, int) in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: are you trying to randomly choose an integer from `delays` array?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally type "(delays, length)" with a comma "," instead of a period "."?

Comment: Yes I am sure of that i didnt use a comma.. and yes pavel im trying to randomly select.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java's built-in [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to pick a random integer between 0 and the last index of your array.

```
import java.util.*;

Random rnd = new Random();
int delayIndex = rnd.nextInt(delays.length);
```

Then access your array and feed that array element into `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: ahhh so its delays.length, i was using delays.getSize() :S let me check this out! 2 minutes and thanks!

Oh yeah this is the problem i got: The method nextInt(int, int) in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: Yes, it's an array, so use delays.length.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a random value from `0...N` where N is the size of the array holding your duration. Once you have that random value, which is an index to the array, just sleep for the duration retrieve from your array at that index position.

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomInt = random.nextInt(delays.length);
sleep(delays[randomInt]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Random r = new Random ();

Thread.sleep (delays [r.nextInt (delays.length)]);
```

Comment: I still get the error:  The method nextInt(int, int) in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: @Echoe Make sure your `Random` is really `java.util.Random`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int index = rnd.nextInt(delays.length);
```

Comment: In you case `index` will be from `-delays.length+1` to `delays.length-1` inclusive, i.e. it can be negative.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov Thanks, forgot that java gives negative results to mod.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int random(int[] delays){
    Random rn = new Random();
    int range = delays.length - 1;
    int pos = rn.nextInt() % range;

    return delays[pos];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sleep(delays[(int)(Math.random() * 100) / 20]);
```

`Math.random()` returns a random number >= 0.0 and < 1.0

Multiply by 100, convert to int, and divide by 20 - you now have a random number 0 - 4.

Or:

```
sleep(delays[new Random().nextInt(5)]);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: Thanks for this, this seems to have my problem solved.. I appreciate your help! Any idea what seems to be the problem with the nextInt thing?

Comment: `Random.nextInt()` takes a single argument; an `int`. And it actually is the upper bound, exclusive. You'll get a number that is between zero and that number minus one.

Comment: You're importing something odd and not `java.util.Random` if you're getting the message you state.

Answer (score 0):

Integer Arrays are not Lists, arrays generally have sequential memory storing of objects(e.g. 0 = 1, 1 = 16, 2 = 0, 3 = 100)
But anyway here is how to do it with an integer array:

```
int[] delays = {1000, 1333, 3443, 1220, 3232};
Random rand = new Random();
Thread.sleep(delays[rand.nextInt(delays.length)]);
```

To do the same with a list with a list of integers it would be something like this:

```
List<Integer> delays = Lists.newArrayList(1000, 1333, 3443, 1220, 3232);
int delay;
for (Iterator<Integer> iter = delays.iterator(); iter.hasNext();){
    Random rand = new Random();
    if(rand.nextInt(delays.size()) == delays.size()){
            delay = iter.next();
            break;
    }
}
Thread.sleep(delay);
```

As you can probably guess i am also new to java but i hope i could help.